# How to filter the item in mysql database into given letter ranges

Tags: mysql

I have a query to filter the result in mysql database into given letter ranges: I want to display the items who starts with letter a-f. I uses this query but I think there is a better query to do that.

```
SELECT DISTINCT title FROM tables WHERE LEFT(title, 1) ='a' AND LEFT(title, 1)='b' .....  AND LEFT(title, 1)='f';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex something like

```
   SELECT DISTINCT title FROM tables WHERE title REGEXP '^[a-f]'
```

---

It's case insensitive. But you might want to remove `DISTINCT` if you do not want single result for uppercase and lowercase word. For example,

```
    mysql> select * from name;
    +------+--------+
    | id   | title  |
    +------+--------+
    |    1 | anisgt |
    |    1 | bnisgt |
    |    1 | dnisgt |
    |    1 | gnisgt |
    |    1 | hnisgt |
    |    1 | Hnisgt |
    |    1 | Pnisgt |
    +------+--------+
    7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> SELECT DISTINCT title FROM name WHERE title REGEXP '^[f-z]';
    +--------+
    | title  |
    +--------+
    | gnisgt |
    | hnisgt |
    | Pnisgt |
    +--------+
    3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> SELECT title FROM name WHERE title REGEXP '^[f-z]';
    +--------+
    | title  |
    +--------+
    | gnisgt |
    | hnisgt |
    | Hnisgt |
    | Pnisgt |
    +--------+
    4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Edit#1** updated case for upper-case, lower case query and example for without distinct

---

However you can force case sensitivity using `binary` key word like

```
    mysql> SELECT DISTINCT binary title FROM name WHERE title REGEXP '^[f-z]';
    +--------------+
    | binary title |
    +--------------+
    | gnisgt       |
    | hnisgt       |
    | Hnisgt       |
    | Pnisgt       |
    +--------------+
    4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Edit:2** case sensitive search added

Comment: Thanks Nishant. Using regular expression on mysql is that letters are case sensitive?

Comment: @christian No, it's case insensitive, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @christian added how to keep distinct as well as case sensitive in search.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL (and probably all databii) evaluate words that begin with 'B' as being greater than 'a' and less than 'c'.

So you can simply check for values between 'a' and 'f'.

```
SELECT DISTINCT title FROM tables WHERE title >= 'a' AND title < 'g';
```

This should be more efficient than a regex (much as I love Regular Expressions), and is easier to read.

Comment: I would recommend using `LEFT(title, 1) <= 'f'` at the end, otherwise Z will be a problematic case. Other than that, this is a nice and simple answer.